# R run multiple scripts at once in terminal

Tags: r, terminal

I have an R function that loads, processes, and saves many files. Here is a dummy version:

```
load_process_saveFiles <- function(onlyFiles = c()){
    
  allFiles <- paste(LETTERS, '.csv', sep = '')
  
  # If desired, only include certain files
  if(length(onlyFiles) > 0){
    allFiles <- allFiles[allFiles %in% onlyFiles]
  }
  
  for(file in allFiles){
    # load file
    rawFile <- file
    
    # Run a super long function
    processedFile <- rawFile
    
    # Save file
    # write.csv(processedFile, paste('./Other/Path/', file, sep = ''), row.names = FALSE)
  
    cat('\nDone with file ', file, sep = '')
  }  
}
```

It has to run through about 30 files, and each one takes about 3 minutes. It can be very time consuming to loop through the entire thing. What I'd like to do is run each one separately at the same time so that it would take 3 minutes all together instead of 3 x 30 = 90 minutes.

I know I can achieve this by creating a bunch of RStudio sessions or many terminal tabs, but I can't handle having that many sessions or tabs open at once.

Ideally, I'd like to have all of the files with separate functions listed in one `batchRun.R` file which I can run from the terminal:

```
source('./PathToFunction/load_process_saveFiles.R')

load_process_saveFiles(onlyFiles = 'A.csv')
load_process_saveFiles(onlyFiles = 'B.csv')
load_process_saveFiles(onlyFiles = 'C.csv')
load_process_saveFiles(onlyFiles = 'D.csv')
load_process_saveFiles(onlyFiles = 'E.csv')
load_process_saveFiles(onlyFiles = 'F.csv')
```

So then run `$ RScript batchRun.R` from the terminal.

I've tried looking up different examples on SO trying to accomplish something similar, but each have some unique features and I just can't get it to work. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Thanks!

Comment: If you happen to be working in Linux, you could do this in a shell script instead of an R script with the background task ampersand symbol `&`  between you `R CMD BATCH . . .` commands (or in a loop).

Comment: You can get a Bash shell on Windows, too: see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about). And in case you find it helpful, [here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) is the section of the Bash manual that describes the `&` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Package `parallel` gives you a number of options. One option is to parallelize the calls to `load_process_saveFiles` and have the loop inside of the function run serially. Another option is to parallelize the loop and have the calls run serially. The best way to assess which approach is more suitable for your job is to time them both yourself.

Evaluating the calls to `load_process_saveFiles` in parallel is relatively straightforward with `mclapply`, the parallel version of the base function `lapply` (see `?lapply`):

```r
parallel::mclapply(x, load_process_saveFiles, mc.cores = 2L)
```

Here, `x` is a list of values of the argument `onlyFiles`, and `mc.cores = 2L` indicates that you want to divide the calls among two R processes.

Evaluating the loop inside of `load_process_saveFiles` in parallel would involve replacing the entire `for` statement with something like

```r
f <- function(file) {
  cat("Processing file", file, "...")
  x <- read(file)
  y <- process(x)
  write(y, file = file.path("path", "to", file))
  cat(" done!\n")
}
parallel::mclapply(allFiles, f, ...)
```

and redefining `load_process_saveFiles` to allow optional arguments:

```
load_process_saveFiles <- function(onlyFiles = character(0L), ...) {
  ## body
}
```

Then you could do, for example, `load_process_saveFiles(onlyFiles, mc.cores = 2L)`.

I should point out that `mclapply` is not supported on Windows. On Windows, you can use `parLapply` instead, but there are some extra steps involved. These are described in the `parallel` vignette, which can be opened from R with `vignette("parallel", "parallel")`. The vignette acts as general introduction to parallelism in R, so it could be worth reading anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel package is useful in this case. And if you are using Linux OS, I would recommend doMC package instead of parallel. This doMC package is useful even for looping over big data used in machine learning projects.